# Copy Gradle dependency res to another Gradle dependency

Tags: android, gradle

I'm currently developing a few plugin for Android and have encountered an issue with resources not being found in the end project which implements all the plugins. To deploy a plugin I use **gradlew install** which generates a **.aar**, this .aar contains the .jar and a **res** folder containing the resource files form that project.

Overview of the problem:

> **Plugin A** uses the google **com.android.support:cardview-v7:23.2.0** dependency.
>
> **Plugin A** now has an external library added to the project and can access the cardview **res** folder.
>
> While compiling **Plugin B** it uses a resource from **Plugin A**, which is an instance of the **cardview**.
>
> This **cardview** uses a resource file from the **res** folder in **Plugin A**.
>
> **Plugin B** now adds **Plugin A** as dependency.
>
> **Plugin B** now has the **res** folder from **Plugin A** but still **misses** resource items from the **res** folder from the **cardview** dependency.

The error thrown at this point is:

`Error:(8) No resource identifier found for attribute 'cardCornerRadius' in package...`

This is because **Plugin B** uses the **cardview** as so:

```
   <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
        android:id="@+id/card_view"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_width="200dp"
        android:layout_height="200dp"
        card_view:cardCornerRadius="4dp">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/info_text"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"/>
    </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
```

The missing **card_view:cardCornerRadius** isn't found in my project, because it is never copied over from **Plugin A** to **Plugin B**.

My question is as follows:

Is there a way to have my **Plugin B** understand what **card_view:cardCornerRadius** is without adding the **com.android.support:cardview-v7:23.2.0** dependency to **Plugin B**, but instead copy it over from **Plugin A**?

Comment: Try import A's R.package into B.

Comment: This doesn't apply to the XML which just searches in the res folder for files.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Raymond, **aar** doesn't ship dependencies! at least it won't be easy as **jar** .. You would need to re-import them (dependencies) again in your app. Lets say **app** uses **plugin-B**(aar). **Plugin-B** uses **plugin-A** as dependency. **Plugin-B** has access to **plgin-A** res, but app won't. You need to import **plugin-A** to your app again. See: [Documentation:Dependency Management](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/dependency_management.html)

> An artifact only notation creates a module dependency which downloads
>   only the artifact file with the specified extension. Existing module
>   descriptors are ignored.

You can try to use transitive to **plugin-A** when generate **aar** from **plguin-B** something like:

```
compile ('com.apipas:plugin_a:1.0.0@aar'){
       transitive=true
}
```

Good luck,'.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. It seems this is what I'm looking for, but transitive doesn't seem to work when compiling them from local .aar files I find by adding flatdirs. After some searching I found that it doesn't work because in this situation the pom file is missing. To actually test your answer I'd need to set up a maven repo.

Comment: Happy that helps .. I did the same thing by reimporting dependencies in app module..

Answer (score 0):

From what xml code you posted ,Are you sure you have added `xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"` in your layout xml and after adding dependency please resync the project